# How do I convert my HEX string into a number?

Tags: javascript

I wish to convert the `whiteHex` variable to a decimal using the `parseInt()` function, and store it in a variable, `whiteDecimal`.

```
var whiteHex = 'ffffff';

var whiteDecimal = parseInt(whiteHex);
```

I am unsure if the above is correct or not. The reason being, that I then wish to subtract 1 from `whiteDecimal` and store it in a variable `offWhiteDecimal`. This is where I am getting stuck. How can I subtract one from the `ffffff` hex value? Am I missing something within the `parseInt` function?

Comment: `parseInt(str,radix)`, use radix 16, it is not inferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for this:

```
var whiteDecimal = parseInt(whiteHex, 16)
console.log(whiteDecimal - 1);
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Syntax

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick!